# Regarding recursion, for loop in Java. Do my understand correct in this context?

Tags: java, loops, recursion

The code written below is about a question that is to 'group a group of words':

```
public class module3_crypto {

    //part 1 - normalizing text
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(groupify("VJKUKUUQOGTGCNNAITGCVVGZV", 4 ));
    }

    public static String groupify(String str_text, int nmbr_of_letters) {
        int pad = str_text.length()%nmbr_of_letters;

        //padding x's to string
        while(pad>0){
            str_text = str_text + 'x';
            pad--;
        }
        //adding space
        for(int i=nmbr_of_letters;i<str_text.length();i=i+nmbr_of_letters){
            str_text = str_text.substring(0,i)+" "+str_text.substring(i,str_text.length());
            i++;
        }
        return str_text;
    }
}
```

I don't really understand this part: `str_text = str_text.substring(0,i)+" "+str_text.substring(i,str_text.length());`. Particularly the part `str_text.length()`. Calling the method with the value of `4`, I know that the `i = 4`. However, what would be the value of `str_text.length()`? Does it take the whole length of  the String ? And thus it keeps on repeating until `i = 16`, and finally only printed the final output that is `VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNA ITGC VVGZ Vx` ? So to say, the gradual 'unfold' for this code is like this ?

```
VJKU KUUQOGTGCNNAITGCVVGZV
VJKU KUUQ OGTGCNNAITGCVVGZV
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNAITGCVVGZV
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNA ITGC VVGZV
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNA ITGC VVGZ Vx
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is asking.

But I guess that, you are asking about, while `str_text` is changing in the `for` loop, then `str_text.length()` is also chaning, then what it will happen (infect) for `str_text.substring(i, str_text.length())`?

`str_text.length()` gets the string length (not-so-seriously speaking, the "character count") of `str_text`. Yes, it is changing during the `for` loop.

According to the doc of [`String.substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), `str_text.substring(i, str_text.length())` will return a new string that its content is from `i` to `str_text.length()` (that is, the end of `str_text`) of `str_text`.

> So to say, the gradual 'unfold' for this code is like this ?

Nearly yes, but a little typo. The correct 'unfold' is:

```
VJKU KUUQOGTGCNNAITGCVVGZVx
VJKU KUUQ OGTGCNNAITGCVVGZVx
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNAITGCVVGZVx
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNA ITGCVVGZVx
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNA ITGC VVGZVx
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNA ITGC VVGZ Vx
VJKU KUUQ OGTG CNNA ITGC VVGZ Vx
```

(Note that 'x' is added before the `for` loop.)
You can test the 'unfold' step by adding a `System.out.println(str_text)` inside the `for` loop.